# Are there an examples of how to use the java api io.humble to encode audio?

Tags: java, audio, video

I was able to follow the examples of how to encode video with io.humble easily enough. But, the only example of including audio that I can find simply encodes audio at the beginning of the video. I can't figure out how to encode samples at arbitrary locations. Using setTimestamp doesn't do anything.

Here is the example I found:
https://www.javatips.net/api/myLib-master/myLib.AGPLv3/myLib.humble.test/src/test/java/com/ttProject/humble/test/BeepSoundTest.java

If I modify the beepSamples() method to increase the "sampleNum" value, I can create a longer tone. But calling the method multiple times or setting samples.setTimestamp() to other values or calling setTimestamp() on the packets, all do nothing.

No matter what I do, the audio always shows up at the beginning of the video.

Ultimately, I want to be able to load arbitrary mp3 files of various audioclips and then merge them into the audio stream of the video at specific timestamps. But I can't even get this example to encode at different points in the video stream.

Comment: I'm not the creator and founder of this fantastic software but soon one will emerge - our lines are busy right now but keep patient and we will get you an operator

Answer (score 2):

The author of this tool unfortunately is not interested in maintaining it or providing examples. Luckily, I found JavaCV which is an alternative that turned out to be really easy to use.

So to anyone else having this problem, I recommend switching to JavaCV. Other options are also JCodec and Xuggler, but Xuggler is deprecated (same author as io.humble) and JCodec apparently is slow and produces much larger files.

Answer (score 0):

If you need support with these kind of projects. I maintain a fork of Xuggler (https://github.com/olivierayache/xuggle-xuggler)..I can provide help on these topics.